# String Equivalence: Counting Substrings

Tags: code-golf, string

## Background

Two strings `s` and `t` are called `k`-Abelian equivalent (shortened to `k`-equivalent in the following) for a positive integer `k` if the following conditions hold:

- The length-`k-1` prefixes of `s` and `t` are equal.
- The length-`k-1` suffixes of `s` and `t` are equal.
- The strings `s` and `t` have the same multisets of length-`k` contiguous substrings.
  In other words, every string of length `k` occurs an equal number of times in `s` and `t`.
  Overlapping occurrences are counted as distinct.

Note that `k`-equivalent strings are always `k-1`-equivalent if `k > 1`, and the third condition implies that `s` and `t` have the same length.
It is also [known](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5104), and possibly useful, that the three conditions above are equivalent to the following one:

- Every non-empty string of length `k` or `k-1` occurs an equal number of times in `s` and `t`.

## An Example

For example, consider the strings `s = "abbaaabb"` and `t = "aabbaabb"`.
Because the strings have the same number of each character, 4 of `a` and 4 of `b`, they are `1`-equivalent.
Consider then `2`-equivalence.
Their first and last characters are the same (both strings begin with `a` and end with `b`), so the first two conditions are satisfied.
The length-`2` substrings of `s` are `aa` (occurs twice), `ab` (twice), `ba` (once), and `bb` (twice), and those of `t` are exactly the same.
This means that the strings are `2`-equivalent.
However, since their second letters are different, the strings are not `3`-equivalent.

## Input

Two alphanumeric strings `s` and `t` of the same length `n > 0`.

## Output

The largest integer `k` between `1` and `n` (inclusive) such that `s` and `t` are `k`-equivalent.
If no such `k` exists, the output is `0`.
In the above example, the correct output would be `2`.

## Rules

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.
Crashing on malformed input is perfectly fine.

## Test Cases

```
"abc" "def" -> 0
"abbaabbb" "aabbbaab" -> 0
"abbaaabb" "aabbbaab" -> 2
"abbaaabb" "aabbaabb" -> 2
"aaabbaabb" "aabbaaabb" -> 3
"aaabbaabb" "aaabbaabb" -> 9
"abbabaabbaababbabaababbaabbabaab" "abbabaabbaababbaabbabaababbabaab" -> 9
"yzxyxx" "yxyzxx" -> 2
"xxxxxyxxxx" "xxxxyxxxxx" -> 5
```

Comment: Why is the solution for the third case `"abbaaabb" "aabbbaab"` = 1? The prefixes `a`, `a` and the suffixes `b`, `b` are the same, and the substrings `aa`, `ab`, `bb`  appear each twice, and the substring `ba` appears once in each string.

Comment: @Jakube prefix of N length

Comment: @Optimizer It says: "The length-`k-1` prefixes of s and t are equal."

Comment: @Jakube Oh right

Comment: @Jakube Good find. There may be something wrong with my reference implementation, or it may be my mistake. I'll change it to a 2 for now, and investigate this later.

Comment: @Zgarb The are also some other mistakes: the correct solutions should be: 0,0,2,2,3,9,9,2,5.

Comment: @Zgarb Corrected it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth): <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```
lfq_TTCmmSm<>dbhkldldQ
```

Input are two strings like `"abc","def"`. Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

### Explanation:

Quite some complicated code. But I'll start easy.

First we want to create all substrings of length `k` of the string `d`.

```
Sm<>dbhkld
 m      ld      apply a function ... to all elements b 
                in the list [0, 1, 2, ..., len(d)-1]
   >db              take the string d starting from the position b
  <   hk            but only hk = k + 1 characters
S               Sort the resulting list.
```

For the string `"acbde"` and `k = 3` this results in `['abc', 'bde', 'cbd', 'de', 'e']`. Notice, that `'de'` and `'e'` are part of this list. This will be quite important in a bit.

I want the substrings for each `k`, one map again.

```
mSm<>dbhkldld
m          ld   apply a function (create all substrings of lenght k) to 
                all elements k in the list [0, 1, 2, ..., len(d)-1]
```

For the string `"acbd"` this results in `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ac', 'bd', 'cb', 'd'], ['acb', 'bd', 'cbd', 'd'], ['acbd', 'bd', 'cbd', 'd']]`.

I want this for both strings, another map.

```
mmSm<>dbhkldldQ
m             Q   apply the function (see above) for all d in input()
```

`[[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'bc', 'c'], ['abc', 'bc', 'c']], [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['de', 'ef', 'f'], ['def', 'ef', 'f']]]` for the input `"abc","def"`, and after a 
zip `C`, this looks `[(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']), (['ab', 'bc', 'c'], ['de', 'ef', 'f']), (['abc', 'bc', 'c'], ['def', 'ef', 'f'])]`.

Now comes the exciting part: We are of course only interest in the `k`s, where the substrings of both words are the same.

```
lfq_TTCmmSm<>dbhkldldQ
 f                         I filter the list for elements T, where
  q_TT                         reversed(T) == T
                           (basically T[0] == T[1])
l                          print the lenght of the resulting list.
                           (= the number of times, where the substrings of length k 
                              of string 1 are equal to the substrings of 
                              length k of string 2)
```

Since we also have the suffixes of length < k in Ts, this also checks, if the suffixes are equal.

The only thing, which I don't check is, if the prefixes are equal. But as it turns out, this isn't necessary. Lemma 2.3 (4<=>5) of the [linked paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5104v1.pdf) says: If the substrings of length `k` are the same, than `pref_{k-1}(string 1) = pref_{k-1}(string 2)` is equivalent to `suff_{k-1}(string 1) = suff_{k-1}(string 2)`. Since the suffixes are equal, the prefixes are also equal.

Comment: the `'ab'` in `g"abbab"3` is from the last two characters, not the prefix. So no, you are not correctly following the spec as you do not check for k-1 length prefix at all

Comment: @Optimizer Lemma 2.3 in the linked paper does the job. I'll add some more explanation.

Comment: Are you saying that checking for k-1 length prefix is not at all required ?

Comment: @Optimizer Exactly

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks for accepting my answer. Too sad, this question didn't get more recognition. I found this was one of the best challenges in a while, and am quite proud of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>51 49 47 41</s> 34 bytes

```
WqN/:Q0=,,{Qf{_,,\f>\)f<$}~=},+W=)
```

Just to get something started. This can surely be golfed a lot. Looking at a different algorithm too.

Input goes as the two strings without quotes on separate lines.

Example:

```
aaabbaabb
aabbaaabb
```

Output:

```
3
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)